# Subversion yields error while loading shared libraries libdb...

Tags: svn, arch-linux, libraries

I recently setup a new Arch Linux computer and when trying to do an `svn checkout` I get this error:

> svn: error while loading shared libraries: libdb-5.3.so: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

What exactly went wrong with this?

I'm using Arch Linux 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try executing

```
ll /usr/lib/libdb*
```

If the library doesn't exist, you have to update the ArchLinux core by running

```
pacman -Suy
```

Comment: This ended up being the problem. I had done a fresh install just a few days earlier and somehow libdb had already went from like 5.2 to 5.3